# How do I capture the output from the ls or find command to store all file names in an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, find, capture, ls

Need to process files in current directory one at a time. I am looking for a way to take the output of `ls` or `find` and store the resulting value as elements of an array. This way I can manipulate the array elements as needed.

Comment: @ SiegeX How do I accept the answers? I have responded and thanked those who replied the best and upvoted them when I got privilege. What more can I do?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To answer your exact question, use the following:

```
arr=( $(find /path/to/toplevel/dir -type f) )
```

#### Example

```
$ find . -type f
./test1.txt
./test2.txt
./test3.txt
$ arr=( $(find . -type f) )
$ echo ${#arr[@]}
3
$ echo ${arr[@]}
./test1.txt ./test2.txt ./test3.txt
$ echo ${arr[0]}
./test1.txt
```

However, if you just want to process files one at a time, you can either use `find`'s `-exec` option if the script is somewhat simple, or you can do a loop over what find returns like so:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  # stuff with "$file" here
done < <(find /path/to/toplevel/dir -type f -print0)
```

Comment: @ChandanChoudhury `read -r -d $'\0'` tells the `read` command to not treat backslash's as a special escape character and to delimit each word with the NUL character since we told `find` to use that as a delimiter with `-print0`.  The `IFS=` part essentially unsets the special Internal Field Separator environment variable so it will not perform word splitting on tabs or spaces or new lines. The TLDR version is that these commands make it so that you can iterate over any filename no matther what kind of characters it contains.

Comment: Would it work to move the `IFS=` in front of the while : `IFS =  ; while ... `?

Comment: Also, is there a difference between this control structure and using a pipe: `find ... | while ....` ?

Answer (score 10):

```
for i in `ls`; do echo $i; done;
```

can't get simpler than that!

edit: hmm - as per Dennis Williamson's comment, it seems you can!

edit 2: although the OP specifically asks how to parse the output of `ls`, I just wanted to point out that, as the commentators below have said, the correct answer is "you don't".  Use `for i in *` or similar instead.

Comment: `for i in *` is even simpler!

Comment: [Don't parse ls!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  `for i in *; do ...` does the same thing except that it isn't confused by funny characters in filenames, and runs faster (because it doesn't spawn another process).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Is there any way to use a variable (containing the path) instead of `*`: `for in in $path/*`

Comment: @PHPLearner: Yes. Just as you posted, but you should quote the variable. `for f in "$path"/*`

Comment: @GordonDavisson `for i in *; do echo "$i" done` will output `*` *in empty* directory.

Comment: @AloisMahdal Yes; shell glob expansion leaves the glob alone if there are no matching files (with `*`, that means "if there are no files"). In many cases this leads to a "file not found" type error, which if what you want. But if it's a problem in your script, either use `shopt -s nullglob` before it (and `shopt -u nullglob` after to avoid problems later on), or in a loop you can add `if [[ ! -e "$i" ]]; then continue; fi` at the beginning of the loop, so it'll skip nonexistent files.

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't need to use ls/find for files in current directory.

Just use a for loop:

```
for files in *; do 
    if [ -f "$files" ]; then
        # do something
    fi
done
```

And if you want to process hidden files too, you can set the relative option:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

This last command works in bash only.

Comment: `%files` should be `$files`.  Also, if you have Bash 4.X you can set `shopt -s globstar` and use `for files in **; do` to be recursive; fully removing the use for `find`

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected the error; by the way, I have Bash 4, but the OP (or other readers as well) may not have it :)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you want to do, you could use xargs:

```
ls directory | xargs cp -v dir2
```

For example. xargs will act on each item returned.

Comment: @Fritschy: If your `cp` supports it you can use `xargs cp -v --target-drectory dir2`.

Comment: @Dennis: it does ;) but it's still missing up there ;)

Comment: @Fritschy: One source of failure would be if any filenames contain spaces. Using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` would fix that. How exactly is it messing up? It works for me.