# How do I store the output from a find command in an array? + bash

Tags: arrays, bash, find

I have the following find command with the following output:

```
$ find -name '*.jpg'
./public_html/github/screencasts-gh-pages/reactiveDataVis/presentation/images/telescope.jpg
./public_html/github/screencasts-gh-pages/introToBackbone/presentation/images/telescope.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(6)Thin Ice.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Snapshot.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Map_Grass.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(8)TheHunters.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(2)Volcanis.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(3)Trench wars.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(8)BigGameHunters.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(8)Turbo.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(4)Blood Bath.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(2)Switchback.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(6)Thin Ice.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/Map_Grass.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(8)TheHunters.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(2)Volcanis.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(3)Trench wars.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(8)BigGameHunters.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(8)Turbo.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(4)Blood Bath.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(2)Switchback.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/Original/(4)Orbital Relay.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Maps/(4)Orbital Relay.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Bg/GameLose.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Bg/GameWin.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Bg/GameStart.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Bg/GamePlay.jpg
./public_html/github/StarCraft-master/img/Demo/Demo.jpg
./public_html/github/flot/examples/image/hs-2004-27-a-large-web.jpg
./public_html/github/minicourse-ajax-project/other/GameLose.jpg
```

How do I store this output in an array? I want it to handle filenames with spaces

I have tried this `arrayname=($(find -name '*.jpg'))` but this just stores the first element. @ I am doing the following which seems to be just the first element?

```
$ arrayname=($(find -name '*.jpg'))
$ echo "$arrayname"
./public_html/github/screencasts-gh-pages/reactiveDataVis/presentation/images/telescope.jpg
$
```

I have tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357277/2392358) but again this just stores the 1st element

Other similar Qs 
[How do I capture the output from the ls or find command to store all file names in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678418/how-do-i-capture-the-output-from-the-ls-or-find-command-to-store-all-file-names)
[How do i store the output of a bash command in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535642/how-do-i-store-the-output-of-a-bash-command-in-a-variable)

Comment: Works for me. Why do you think you are getting just the 1st element? What code are using to verify it? (Then again, it has a problem where it will split lines that contain space.)

Comment: I am doing an echo on that array and it is just showing the 1st element, can you correct my ways, see my edited Q

Comment: If you are doing `echo $arrayname`, that shows the first element. If you are doing `echo "${arrayname[@]}"`, it shows the whole array.

Comment: can i print it in this format ['a','b','c'...]?

Comment: With work, yes. Automatically, no. Use Ruby or another nice scripting language if you want convenience.

Comment: don't have ruby, will just use np++ for now.

Comment: `printf '["' && sh -c 'IFS=",";printf "$*"' '' "${arrrayname[@]}" && echo '"]'` might work. You will not get proper escaping though. `ruby -rjson -e 'puts JSON.dump(ARGV)' "${arrayname[@]}"` should work well if you have Ruby; similar things with other nice languages.

Comment: close that gives ["a,b,c,...,z"]. note there is also 3 r's in arrrayname

Comment: Eh yeah, ignore the first one, that's a brain fart. Needs a loop and everything, and you'd still have a problem with stuff containing quotes or backslashes. Lots of work to make bash into something it's not.

Comment: @amadan: Try `declare -p arrayname`

Answer (score 3):

If you know with certainty that your filenames will not contain newlines, then

```
mapfile -t arrayname < <(find ...)
```

If you want to be able to handle any file

```
arrayname=()
while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
    arrayname+=("$filename")
done < <(find ... -print0)
```

---

`echo "$arrayname"` will only show the first element of the array. It is equivalent to `echo "${arrayname[0]}"`. To dump an array:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arrayname[@]}"
# ............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ must use exactly this form, with the quotes.
```

---

`arrayname=($(find ...))` is still wrong. It will store the file `./file with spaces.txt` as 3 separate elements in the array.

Comment: tried that `$ arrayname=()
$ while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
>     arrayname+=("$filename")
> done < <(find '*.jpg' -print0)
find: `*.jpg': No such file or directory
$` and got this error `find: `*.jpg': No such file or directory`

Comment: @glennjackman That's a great answer. May I also add this one `while read -rd '';do arr[i++]=$REPLY;done < <(find . -name '*.jpg' -print0)` , executable in Bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sufficiently recent version of bash, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by just using a `**` glob.

```
shopt -s globstar
files=(**/*.jpg)
```

The first line enables the feature. Once enabled, `**` in a glob pattern will match any number (including 0) of directories in the path.

Using the glob in the array definition makes sure that whitespace is handled correctly.

To view an array in a form which could be used to define the array, use the `-p` (print) option to the `declare` builtin:

```
declare -p files
```

Comment: very good. I just answered the question but this solves the problem.

Comment: Whenever I enable globstar I also use `nullglob`